# Android Jetpack Compose: Video Player restarts on navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, exoplayer

My requirement is to play video from the URL on the home screen

when a user navigates to other screens and comes back to the home screen, the video has to be resumed. The problem is player restarts every time comes back to the home screen.

Is there any idea/suggestions to implement??

Comment: Store the timestamp of the track that is playing in a state and use it to restore the video playback when the user returns back.